# Validar se o Nome do Usuario esta contido na senha com Kotlin

Tags: java, string, regex, kotlin

estou com um problema onde eu preciso impedir que a senha fornecida pelo usuario contenha o nome ou partes do nome dele. As regras são as seguintes:

1. Não pode ter nenhum nome ou sobrenome do usuário na senha
2. Não pode ter nenhuma parte  maior ou igual a 3 caracteres do nome ou do sobrenome do usuario na senha.

O codigo que eu tenho até agora é este que consegue validar apenas a regra 1.

```
fun containsUsername(data: PasswordData): Boolean {    
   val partesUsername = data.username.split(" ").joinToString("|")    
   val nomePattern = Regex("""(?i).*($partesUsername).*""")   

   return nomePattern.containsMatchIn(data.password)
}
```

Exemplos para facilitar o entendimento:

```
fun main() {
    val nomeUsuario = "Maria Antonia dos Santos"
    val senha1 = "AbcMariaXyz" // Senha inválida devido a "Maria"
    val senha2 = "AntoniaMaria" // Senha inválida devido a "Maria"
    val senha3 = "Maria123" // Senha inválida devido a "Maria"
    val senha4 = "AntoniaSenha" // Senha inválida devido a "Antonia"
    val senha5 = "Dos_123" // Senha inválida devido a "Dos"
    val senha6 = "SantosAbc" // Senha inválida devido a "Santos"
    val senha7 = "OniSenha" // Senha inválida devido a "Oni"
    val senha8 = "MarSenha" // Senha inválida devido a "Mar"
    
    println(containsUsername(senha1, nomeUsuario)) // true
    println(containsUsername(senha2, nomeUsuario)) // true
    println(containsUsername(senha3, nomeUsuario)) // true
    println(containsUsername(senha4, nomeUsuario)) // true
    println(containsUsername(senha5, nomeUsuario)) // true
    println(containsUsername(senha6, nomeUsuario)) // true
    println(containsUsername(senha7, nomeUsuario)) // true
    println(containsUsername(senha8, nomeUsuario)) // true
}
```

Comment: Sua dúvida é "como implementar" a tal regra #2? Se sim, deixe claro, por gentileza. Ou ainda, se já tiver algum código para a regra #2 e quiser ajuda com este, forneça-o e deixe claro. Assim, poderemos melhor ajudá-lo.

Comment: Sobre a regra 2, vc só precisa verificar as substrings de tamanho 3. Por exemplo, se o nome for "Maria", e a senha tiver "Mari", ela automaticamente contém "Mar" - ou seja, só precisa verificar o caso de 3 caracteres. Dito isso, basta pegar o nome e testar as 3 primeiras letras, depois da primeira até a quarta letra, depois da segunda até a quinta e assim por diante. Nem precisa de regex: https://ideone.com/77Szqv

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Obrigado pelas respostas amigos, mas eu consegui a resolver este problema tomando como base a solução em outro forum.

```
function containsUsername(name, password) {
  // convert the strings to lowercase for easier searching
  // spaces should apparently not count, so split the name into parts
  nameparts = name.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  lpwd = password.toLowerCase();
  
  for(part of nameparts) {
    // check at most 3 characters at a time from each part
    end = part.length > 3 ? part.length - 3 : 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= end; ++i) {
      if(lpwd.indexOf(part.substr(i, 3)) != -1) return true;
    }
  }
  return false; // no match found
}

username = "Maria Antonia dos Santos";
  
const passwords = [
  "AbcMariaXyz", // Invalid password due to "Maria"
  "AntoniaMaria", // Invalid password due to "Maria"
  "Maria123", // Invalid password due to "Maria"
  "AntoniaSenha", // Invalid password due to "Antonia"
  "Dos_123", // Invalid password due to "Dos"
  "SantosAbc", // Invalid password due to "Santos"
  "OniSenha", // Invalid password due to "Oni"
  "MarSenha", // Invalid password due to "Mar"
];
     
for (pwd of passwords) {
  console.log("testing " + pwd);
  res = containsUsername(username, pwd);
  console.log(res);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

**Tente usar a seguinte função:**

```
fun validarSenha(nome: String, sobrenome: String, senha: String): Boolean {
// Verificar se o nome ou sobrenome estão na senha
val nomeRegex = Regex("\\b${Regex.escape(nome)}\\b", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
val sobrenomeRegex = Regex("\\b${Regex.escape(sobrenome)}\\b", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)

if (nomeRegex.containsMatchIn(senha) || sobrenomeRegex.containsMatchIn(senha)) {
    return false
}

// Verificar se partes do nome ou sobrenome estão na senha
for (i in 0 until nome.length - 2) {
    val parteNome = nome.substring(i, i + 3)
    val parteNomeRegex = Regex(Regex.escape(parteNome), RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
    if (parteNomeRegex.containsMatchIn(senha)) {
        return false
    }
}

for (i in 0 until sobrenome.length - 2) {
    val parteSobrenome = sobrenome.substring(i, i + 3)
    val parteSobrenomeRegex = Regex(Regex.escape(parteSobrenome), RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
    if (parteSobrenomeRegex.containsMatchIn(senha)) {
        return false
    }
}

// Se não houver correspondências, a senha é válida
return true
```

}

Comment: Muito obrigado por responder, mas na verdade eu consegui a resposta neste forum:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77047697/how-to-validate-if-a-name-is-contained-in-a-password